# Labeling Graduated Symbols in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I am looking to place labels showing the exact number associated with a graduated symbol. I have the labels, and the symbols, but cannot seem to get them placed in the same location.[image: example of mislabeling]

Can someone shed light on how to make this happen in ArcMap 10.x?

Comment: Which version of ArcMap are you using? Using the Maplex Engine for labelling will make controlling the labels a lot easier. You can turn it on in the Labelling Toolbar or under the General Tab in the Layer Properties.

Answer (score -2):

You could try going to the 'Labels' tab for your graduated symbols layer. From there, if you choose 'Symbol', and then 'Edit Symbol' you'll be able to set label placement preferences and offset distances that should give you a good amount of control over where the label ends up.

Another option because you only have a few symbols would be to add labels individually in the "Layout View" section of ArcMap!

Comment: Hopefully this can help clarify:

- The graduated symbols are being generated from a polygon layer
- The labels are being applied in the layer properties "Labels" tab (which is separate from the "Symbology" tab)

I'm wondering if there is a way to link the two tabs together, or if there is a way inside of the "Symbology" tab to apply labels from the Value Field the graduated symbols are being generated from.